# SQL Server locked on system process

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2012:

Tried to do a database copy on a live database - to detach and re-attached.

It errored then the database stated it was in single user mode.

Attempted to run code like:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
--do you stuff here
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET MULTI_USER
```

Database says it can't because it deadlocked on live processes on the DB.

Can't kill live processes because they are below 50, which are system processes.

This is where all of the online articles on the subject break down.

I have tried to cut off all other connections to database and restart database, however these system processes remain alive.

---

Any rapid answer would be very appreciated so I can get my DB back online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### [Help! I'm stuck in Single User Mode and can't get out!](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/pearlknows/2014/04/07/help-i-m-stuck-in-single-user-mode-and-can-t-get-out/)
>
> **SQL Server 2012**
>
> ```
> USE [master] 
> SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH 
> ALTER DATABASE [StuckDB] SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT 
> ALTER DATABASE [StuckDB] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
> ```

<sub>[source](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/pearlknows/2014/04/07/help-i-m-stuck-in-single-user-mode-and-can-t-get-out/)</sub>

Comment: You're the best. And nice GIF, btw.